# iOS PhoneGap app upgraded to Cordova 2.1 - content ignores status bar entirely

Tags: ios, cordova

I just finished upgrading an iOS PhoneGap app to Cordova 2.1. The app builds fine, but when running it on the simulator, the content of the app seems to completely ignore the fact that the status bar is there. 20px of content is hidden underneath the status bar now and I cannot seem to add padding to shift it down even.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can I please ask you, how did you upgrade your phonegap, I need to upgrade phonegap 1.4.1 to cordova latest version. I have a question post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266259/upgrade-phonegap-for-ios-from-1-4-1-to-latest

Comment: Just follow the instructions in the PhoneGap download - all of the upgrade steps are detailed inside.

Comment: Hi Robbo should I upgrade from 1.4.1 to 1.5 first and then from 1.5 to 1.9 and then 2.2. Or can I just upgrade to 2.2 straight away. Thanks

Comment: You have to go from version to version, you can't jump from 1.4 to 2.2. You'll be better off though if you start a new project with 2.2 and just import your assets there.

Comment: Hi Robbo, yes I created a new project with 2.2, still working on it. but it is a good approach. Thank you :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you upgraded your application to use PhoneGap 2.1 from another version, your MainViewController.m file may not be up to date.

You need to have the following code in it:

```
#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // Set the main view to utilize the entire application frame space of the device.
    // Change this to suit your view's UI footprint needs in your application.
    self.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Once you have this function, your App will be back to normal!

(Solution found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/PpGEFmZ96MI))

Comment: I can't believe this was left out of the upgrade guide. The `EnableLocation=YES` was a fun one as well ... so lame. Thanks for the great answer tho!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want the status bar to apear.

Check to make sure the code does not have this line:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO]
```

Also, you may have set it to be hidden in interface builder.

Another place is in the info.plist for your app,  check for this line

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
```

Comment: That's the strange thing, the app is acting like the status bar is hidden, but it's not (and I don't want the status bar hidden either). I tried adding UIStatusBarHidden - NO to Cordova.plist but that had no effect.

Comment: in xcode, do a cmd-shift-f and search for setStatusBarHidden, see what the value is.

Comment: No results found is what I get back.